# failing to compare hashed password password with bcrypt.js in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, bcrypt

[Here is my code which i used to login. I am using simple password 1234 but it still returning false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc0SR.png)

Answer (score 0):

thankyou all i was using async method to campare the hashed value with user entered value first and morever when i just used bcrypt.hash() method it did not work either sync or async then instead i generate salt and the hshed the password and used sync method to compare the password which worked for me